# Unable to get slide effect in fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to achieve slide effect between fragment.
Like following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxHeT.gif

Following is my code.

```
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, numberFragment, NUM_FRAGMENT_TAG).addToBackStack(null);

 fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_right_to_left, R.anim.exit_right_to_left,
                R.anim.enter_left_to_right, R.anim.exit_left_to_right);

 fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Following are my xml files.

**enter_right_to_left**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

**exit_right_to_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

**enter_left_to_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

**exit_left_to_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide) or [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide-2)

Here another examples:

[ViewPager](https://www.journaldev.com/10096/android-viewpager-example-tutorial) and [ViewPager2](https://www.journaldev.com/26148/android-viewpager2)

Its very simple to use in your app.